# google app script map tutorial change

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script

Trying to use: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/maps_tutorial?hl=en I receive the map correctly. However, I would like for the map to remain on one tab. The bottom of the code reads:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(ui);
```

And I think I should change it to

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('restaurants').show(ui);
```

so that the map remains on one tab. But it gives me an error message. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error message because there is no `.show()` method for the `Sheet` Class. The ui is attached to a Spreadsheet, not a Sheet. (Comparing to Excel, Spreadsheet == Workbook, Sheet == Worksheet aka tab.)

If you want to ensure that the sheet (tab) containing the map is visible, use [`Sheet.activate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate%28%29).

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var mapSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Map");  // Assuming sheet is named Map
 mapSheet.activate();                      // Bring Map to front
 ss.show(ui);                              // Open UI
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to name **the tab of the spreadsheet** as 'restaurants', not the spreadsheet.